# std::vector Erase - does it de-allocate automatically?

Tags: c++, stdvector

In below code **mKnownRSList** is of type:

```
  std::vector<RSAddress *>
```

where **RSAddress** is a class I wrote. The functiop **removeItem** removes an item from this vector.

My question here is that after calling the erase function on mKnownRSList, am I supposed to de-allocate the address pointed by the iterator returned by std::remove_if. Currently I explicitly issue a delete call on the de-referenced iterator named last. Do you think this approach is correct? Thanks.

```
void 
ABC::removeItem(RSAddress * rsAddr)
{
   auto last = 
   std::remove_if(mKnownRSList.begin(),
                  mKnownRSList.end(),
                 [rsAddr]( RSAddress * o )
                 {
                   return (*o == *rsAddr);
                 });

 mKnownRSList.erase(last, mKnownRSList.end());

 delete *last;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should delete what is pointed to by your pointer inside the container *first* and then you remove/erase the actual pointer from the container.

What you're doing here is dereferencing an iterator that points to something that no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think this approach is correct?

Nope. The correct way is to use smart_pointers like [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). If you will, then you should only `erase` it. like this

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr< RSAddress  > > mKnownRSList;
...

mKnownRSList.erase( std::remove_if(mKnownRSList.begin(),
                                   mKnownRSList.end(),
                                   [rsAddr]( const std::shared_ptr< RSAddress > & o )
                                   {
                                       return (*o == *rsAddr);
                                   }),
                    mKnownRSList.end()
);
```

Comment: I would second borisbn. This is the safest approach.